# How can I refer documents characterised by technical jargon?

Tags: idioms, formal-language, terminology

I was wondering if there is any word or expression to refer documents characterized by technical jargon, such as clinical reports or patents.

I could use "technical reports" but, for example in the case of clinical reports might sound not appropriate. So, what term or expression might be more suitable?

Comment: What are you wanting to express? Do you want to say that the technical jargon is a good thing, or a bad thing? Appropriate, misused, or overused? What kind of sentence would you like to use this word in? I can think of a few different alternatives, but I’d need to know more about what you intend to say.

Comment: I would express the document with technical jargon are particular, are different from other general purpose documents.
So, I am looking for a word or expression which summarize this kind of particular document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you describe falls under the umbrella of [**technical writing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_writing), which Wikipedia defines as:

> any written form of ... technical communication used in a variety of technical and occupational fields, such as computer hardware and software, engineering, chemistry, aeronautics, robotics, finance, medical, consumer electronics, and biotechnology.

---

Informally, you might also say that the clinical report is "not for the layperson." You'll see this phrase used every now and then in book reviews, such as these:

> *It’s wonderfully written with a lot of technical calculations that are [not for the layperson](https://simplifaster.com/articles/10-books-performance-coaches/)...*
>
> *In 1931, mathematician Alfred Korzybski presented a paper on mathematical semantics. It’s [not for the layperson](https://medium.com/swlh/the-map-is-not-the-territory-c83505be942f), however, it contains a gem.*
>
> *Dr. Verkhonshansky and Dr. Siff have written an absolute masterpiece, but this one’s [not for the layperson](http://rdellatraining.com/site/the-12-best-strength-training-books-ever-written) at all. If you are a science nerd, as I am, you will love the deep dive and complexity of the massive information presented*...
>
> *The most comprehensive book to date was written by Robert Tisserand and Rodney Young. This book however is [not for the layperson](http://www.unusualhealth.com/learning-about-essential-oils/) (5.2 pounds of small type and very sciencey — full of chemistry and research)*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
However, I have some doubts about the usage of "tecnhnical writing": do someone really refers to the difficulty of clinical reports by "technical writing"?
I agree is correct, I am not sure is completely appropriate or common.

Comment: “technical writing” refers to many things. I wouldn’t expect people to refer to clinical reports as _technical writing_ on a regular basis; however, as I say in my answer, I think they “fall under the umbrella.”

Comment: Thank you!
I accept your answer but I still look for some alternative formulation.